# Third party pack cannot be found likely because the corresponding app is restricted

Tags: whatsapp-stickers

When i add sticker from assets it was working but when i have to Download my custome stickerpack from serve and add to it whatsapp then getting same issue "Third party pack cannot be found likely because the corresponding app is restricted, sdk: 29 ,power saving mode: false"
my "Add to whatsapp" button code is

```
intent.setAction("com.whatsapp.intent.action.ENABLE_STICKER_PACK");
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_ID, stickerPack.identifier.replace(" ",""));
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_AUTHORITY, BuildConfig.CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_NAME, *stickerPack.name*);
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_PACK);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG+"aba", "onCreate: "+e.toString());
                }
```